# use multi level/chain of entity reference fields to create a list of nodes using views

Tags: entities, views

I have 3 content types: Outline, Chapter and notes.

Chapter and Notes have 2 entity reference fields chap_outline_reference and note_outline_reference respectively referring to outline.
On the chapter nodes i want to populate a jump menu of all the notes referring to the same outline as the chapter.
I'm using Views 7.x-3.13 and Drupal 7.41.

I created a block view using the following relationship:

Entity Reference: Referencing entity ( for chap_outline_reference)

Entity Reference: Referenced Entity ( for note_outline_reference) and i'm using the above relationship in this relationship.

I am unable to figure out the contextual filter.
I tried using Content:nid with either of the above relations, but that didn't work.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everybody stuck in a similar situation and not having advanced knowledge; this is how I solved it:
I broke the problem into 2 views and used "view field view" module to connect the 2 views.

In the first view; i used a relationship(entity referencing) and contextual filter(Content:nid) to reach the nid of the outline from the chapter nid.

In the second view; i used a relationship(entity referenced) and contextual filter(Content:nid) to reach the nid of the notes from the outline nid.

Using the Global: view field (from view field view) module I substituted the Outline nid for the contextual filter (Content:nid) in the second view.